# VB.NET Nested With statements from different scopes

Tags: vb.net, data-structures, nested, with-statement

I am wondering if this is possible.  I have a List Table (lstTable) that is on the same form that I am trying to fill in with information from a public structure (ELEM_DATA).  I understand nested with statements will work if it is within the same scope but how can I do this with example 2 below:

Example 1:

```
With me.lstTable.Items(RECORD)
     .SubItems(1).text = ELEM_DATA(RECORD).name
     .SubItems(2).text = ELEM_DATA(RECORD).number
end with
```

Example 2:

```
With me.lstTable.Items(RECORD)
     With ELEM_DATA(RECORD)
     .SubItems(1).text = .name
     .SubItems(2).text = .number
     end with
end with
```

I didnt know if it is possible or if it would be as simple as changing (.name) to something else.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you did?

Comment: When I tried it kept saying .name was not a member of lstTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested With statements work (see comment about conflicts). Unfortunately you can't use the outer members inside the inner with.  But since your outer WITH is a refernce type you could use a local variable to "alias" it as you suggest in you comment.

```
Dim l = me.lstTable.Items(RECORD) ' requires 2008 and option infer
With ELEM_DATA(RECORD)
   l.SubItems(1).text = .name
End With
```

Here's a link to show how nested WITH statements can used.

http://ideone.com/agjne

Comment: But only on unique members. If both classes have members with same name, then those members cant be used with the dot-notation and must be called explicit using the "full path".

Comment: @Stefan: yeah, I meant to include that, but it got lost in my editing.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something similar as With ELEM_DATA(RECORD) As E and do E.name and E.number instead of doing the full path?

Comment: @jinanwow: you can't do that directly like you can in SQL, but you could copy the structure to another variable...you could also create a sub that does the copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
'EXAMPLE:

With New Object() {1, 2} 'With block 1
     Dim debug_1 As Object = .ToArray(0) 'Value 1 from object of block 1
         With New Object() {3, 4}  'With block 2
                 Dim debug_2 As Object = .ToArray(0)  'Value 3 from block 2
                 'How get 2 from block 1 of Object() {1, 2}?
                 '>>>
         End With
End With
'SOLUTION
With New Object() {1, 2}    
     With New Object() {3, 4}.Concat(.ToArray)
          Dim debug_3 As Object = .ToArray(3)  'got value 2 from outer WITH block 1 [Object() {1, 2}]
          '---//---//---
     End With
     '---//---//---
End With
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25775721)